# php session management in socket services

Tags: php, api, session

I'm considering building a security service in PHP that would hold user credential information , the most important of them would be tokens of logged in users. This service would be accessed by some kind of an API (REST, SOAP, whatever) by another API (an external user connects through a website API which checks credentials in another API - the one we're considering now).

There is a possibility to store tokens (and other information) in RDBMS. But this solution doesn't seem clean to me (tokens will remain in the database even if they're already expired, I would have to implement a mechanism for clearing expired sessions, etc). I was thinking about using native PHP session management (`$_SESSION`). Is that possible? Does anyone have experience with doing such things?

I thought of following problems:

- when a PHP-based website is deployed on www server, users access the URL via browser and their native sessions are created using browser cookies. If there was one webpage API that would connect to security API, would there be only one session object all the time? Is it configurable?
- How precisely sessions are created and how can I affect the mechanism (e.g. not to base it on cookies)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to use a database.

Let me start out with explaining the general concept of sessions. Sessions can be seen as server-side cookies. The location of the $_SESSION variable storage is determined by PHP's session.save_path configuration. Usually this is /tmp on a Linux/Unix system. Sessions have a session-parameter of the client associated with them. When a session_start or something like that is issued, the server will retrieve the file/session based on the session-parameter provided by client. As these are just stored files, it is possible for the server to read the sessions of other clients.

That brings me to the second problem you describe. If I am correct you want to have some api request information about a session of some user. Based on the first paragraph, you hopefully understand that the purpose of sessions isn't to use it as some sort of global storage. Of course it is possible. You could have the foreign APIs include the session-parameter or you could read the session-files manually, but to me these seem dirty fixes. It just isn't what sessions are build for.

The only other thing which attracts you to using sessions is the automatic timeout of sessions. However this simple logic you could easily implement when using a database. What you should do is register the time of the last activity of the user in your database. When an API requests the data of a user you can simply check whether the current time - the last active time is lower than a certain threshold. If that is not the case, the session expired and, at the same time, you can drop the session from the table. This is the more or less the same general method as sessions internally use, which requires no regular cronjobs (although they still could be useful to cleanup the database) to remove sessions.

So don't be afraid to use a database to store data, after all they are build (and optimized) to do that exact thing.